# Perform arithmetic between two rings of integers (with different mods) in SAGE

Tags: python, math, cryptography, sage, dsa

I'm trying to digitally sign a test message in Sage using DSA (DSS). After running my code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_sage_input_28.py", line 10, in <module>
    exec compile(u'open("___code___.py","w").write("# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\\n" + _support_.preparse_worksheet_cell(base64.b64decode("IyBDaGVjayB0aGUgc2lnbmF0dXJlCmNoZWNrX3NpZyhtLHAscSxnLHIscyx5KQ=="),globals())+"\\n"); execfile(os.path.abspath("___code___.py"))
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/tmpUuKk65/___code___.py", line 3, in <module>
    exec compile(u'check_sig(m,p,q,g,r,s,y)
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/tmppjN9Gi/___code___.py", line 7, in check_sig
    u_2 = mod(r*w,q)
  File "element.pyx", line 1701, in sage.structure.element.RingElement.__mul__ (sage/structure/element.c:14531)
  File "coerce.pyx", line 856, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op (sage/structure/coerce.c:8169)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '*': 'Ring of integers modulo 98007532214006523718033513010741500921668410005086660781341579786663143142637' and 'Ring of integers modulo 44449'
```

The offending line is: `u_2 = mod(r*w,q)`. I think the issue here is I'm multiplying `r` and `w` where:

```
r = mod(mod(g^k,p),q)
w = mod(1/s,q)
```

However, these are both `mod q`. Why can't I perform a multiplication on them? Is there some kind of casting I have to do?

Here's a link to the full (still small) sage sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw2qz.png

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to multiply two rings together. Multiplication is not an operation that is defined for rings. Multiplication is an operation that is defined for elements contained in rings. I have some doubts that r and w are defined the way you think they are.

Comment: @Zéychin, those are the only definitions for `r` and `w` I have. I could post my sheet if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: I can take a look at it. I can't make any promises. I am not too familiar with Sage, but am very familiar with the mathematics.

Comment: FWIW. You might get more traction for this question on the [sage-support Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support). There is a proposal to create a [Stackexchange site for Sage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70511/sage).

Comment: @Zéychin, for some reason I couldn't make the sheet public. I uploaded a screenshot of it and added the link in the description. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Perhaps the error is in that they are actually in different bases. `q`'s value is changed during the execution of the program. I am not familiar enough with Sage's approach to the integers mod n to be certain. Try setting `r = mod(r,q)`, `w = mod(w,q)` just before the offending line.

Comment: @Zéychin, I removed the logic from the functions and made the calculations inline....and it worked. I'm wondering if `q` somehow got changed when it got passed into a different context?

Comment: You defined `q` globally. Take a look at your code to see if you assigned `q` a different value elsewhere. Doing a search on `q =` would be a good start.

Comment: See also http://ask.sagemath.org/question/25001/cant-multiply-two-variables-together-due-to-type-i-think/